# other language word inside sql like query not working?

Tags: c#, sql

the following sql query

```
SELECT [name] ,[mail]  FROM [UserTable]  WHERE  name LIKE '%test%'
```

is working. but

```
SELECT [name] ,[mail]  FROM [UserTable]  WHERE  name LIKE '%pārbaude%'
```

is not working (does not return corresponding row even its available). the difference is the word inside % (pārbaude) other language(Latvian) word.

But when i execute

```
SELECT [name] ,[mail]  FROM [UserTable]
```

is coming. How can i achieve with where condition?

Comment: It does not return corresponding row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your column is nchar / nvarchar, use **N** to represent unicode

```
SELECT [name] ,[mail]  FROM [UserTable]  
WHERE  name LIKE N'%pārbaude%'
```

Answer (score 1):

if the type of name column is not `nvarchar` try with changing it to nvarchar, unless you have to pass the characters with the same **codepage** in your db

Comment: hi @FarhangAmary the column type is SpecialPurposeColumn. I can not change that. Is there any other way to achieve it?

Comment: hi, I don't understand why the type of **name** column in **userTable** should be **Special-Purposed** it's not need to be. the other point is look at your database **Collation** and check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [name] ,[mail]  FROM [UserTable]  
WHERE  name LIKE '%pārbaude%'
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS;
```